# How to reset cache in project Visual Studio(winform)?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2017

Very weird things happens in my project Visual Studio.

On the main Form I have three radiobuttons. One of them is selected. It is first radiobutton with property: `checked:true`. It has name `radioButton8`.

When I start project I see that selected the second radio button with name `radioButton1`.

I tried to find this element in project by its namw `radioButton1` in main Form. But there is not nothing, that can set this in checked state.

What does happend with VS? How to clear project fully and reset cache?

Also sometimes toolbox becomes to empty.

I did searhing in current project and have found only this in `Main.Designer`:

```
   // radioButton1
            // 
            this.radioButton1.AutoSize = true;
            this.radioButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 58);
            this.radioButton1.Name = "radioButton1";
            this.radioButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 17);
            this.radioButton1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.radioButton1.TabStop = true;
            this.radioButton1.Text = "Прошли тест";
            this.radioButton1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.radioButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton1_Click);
            //
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I also face this issue many times. When i clean the project/solution and Build the solution again, also before this i have to delete the obj folder in your  project folder.